# Leaflet - GeoJSON - co-ordinates

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to use GEOJSON along with leaflet and am attempting to display a linestring between two locations , by dynamically entering their coordinates in the geoJSON feature

```
var geojsonFeature = { "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "Coors Field",
                        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
                    },
                            "geometry": {
                            "type": "LineString",
                            "coordinates": [[77.68148,12.91127],[77.60943,12.91125]]
                        }
                    };
                    L.geoJson(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

Is  there any way by which i could enter coordinates in the geoJsonfeature dynamically using a loop , if so what would be the syntax to form the coordinates array this way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not just write:

```
geojsonFeature.geometry.coordinates = whaterveryouwant;
```

Or am I missing something?